# Shuffling a Deck in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, list, random

Here is my source:

```
Public Class Deck

    Dim deckList As New List(Of Card)

    Sub ShuffleDeck()
        'creates a new deck to copy to, a list of random numbers, and a randomizer object to make random number in a range
        Dim tempDeck As New List(Of Card)
        Dim listOfRandomNumbers As New List(Of Integer)
        Dim randomizer As New Random
        Dim randomNumber As Integer

        'this generates a random number then adds it to the list of random numbers if there is no others already like it in the list of random numbers
        Do While (listOfRandomNumbers.Count() < 52)

            randomNumber = randomizer.Next(0, 51)

            If listOfRandomNumbers.Contains(randomNumber) = False Then
                listOfRandomNumbers.Add(randomNumber)
            End If

        Loop

        Dim index As Integer
        Do While (index < 51)
            'this adds a card to the tempDeck at a random index of the deck list
            tempDeck.Add(deckList(listOfRandomNumbers(index)))
            index = index + 1
        Loop

        'assigning the deck from the ordered one to the shuffled one
        deckList = tempDeck

    End Sub

End Class
```

I am trying shuffle a Deck of cards, but I'm getting stuck in an infinite loop here when I attempt to make my listOfRandomNumbers contain unique values that aren't repeated.

```
Do While (listOfRandomNumbers.Count() < 52)

     randomNumber = randomizer.Next(0, 51)

     If listOfRandomNumbers.Contains(randomNumber) = False Then
          listOfRandomNumbers.Add(randomNumber)
     End If

Loop
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I can't check right now, but i want to point out that your shuffle algorithm is very inefficient. It's possible that your code isn't buggy but rather it is working and just taking a really long time!

Comment: If I were you, I would decrease the decksize to a really small number (like 4), and seeing if it works then.

Comment: Next(0, 51) => 0~50, which would always return true => infinite loop, easy way to solve => Next(0, 52), but it is not preferred to generate random number everytime, can you please create a 52 elements array, pick randomly and remove that item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I look into your codes, tried and debug it. I put all the `randomNumber` in a listBox to see what integers are being stored.
Your codes:

```
Do While (listOfRandomNumbers.Count() < 52)

    randomNumber = randomizer.Next(0, 51)

    If listOfRandomNumbers.Contains(randomNumber) = False Then
         listOfRandomNumbers.Add(randomNumber)
    End If

Loop
```

It doesn't stop the loop because `randomizer.Next(0, 51)` contains the numbers from 0 - 50. So that `listOfRandomNumbers.Count()` is equal to 51

You have this line:

```
If listOfRandomNumbers.Contains(randomNumber) = False Then
```

This causes the infinite loop because numbers 0 - 50 is already added to `listOfRandomNumbers` (as declared in the randomizer.Next(0, 51), so it will always return `true`

Use `randomNumber = randomizer.Next(0, 52)` to include 51.
Your problem in infinite loop will be solved.

Comment: That was it. I understand this is fairly inefficient given how many iterations the loop has to go through (usually around 200 - 300 times) just to fill 52 indices. I might end up going with another implementation suggested by others.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the simplest option is like so:

```
Private ReadOnly randomizer As New Random

Private Sub SuffleDeck()
    Dim values = deckList.ToArray()
    Dim keys = values.Select(Function(value) randomizer.NextDouble()).ToArray()

    Array.Sort(values, keys)

    deckList.Clear()
    deckList.AddRange(values)
End Sub
```

Note that the `Random` variable is a member.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that the call to `randomizer.Next(0, 51)` produces numbers from `0` to `50` inclusive. If you want `51` to be included you need to call it with `randomizer.Next(0, 52)`.

It effectively should be:

```
randomNumber = randomizer.Next(0, listOfRandomNumbers.Count())
```

Overall though, you're better off doing this:

```
Dim randomizer As New Random

Sub ShuffleDeck()

    Dim listOfRandomNumbers = _
        Enumerable _
            .Range(0, 52) _
            .OrderBy(Function (x) randomizer.Next()) _
            .ToList()
```

Comment: I used to recommend that sort of thing but it was pointed out to me that it's actually bad because it's going to result in different random values being generated for the same original value each time it gets compared, which means that the same two original values could be ordered differently if compared more then once within the same run.  That's why I now recommend, as I did in my own answer, that a single set of keys be generated upfront, so that the same random value will be associated with an original value every time it is compared.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - I'm not following what you mean by "different random values being generated for the same original value each time it gets compared". Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorting a list involves repeatedly comparing pairs of items and moving them if appropriate. With your code, comparing a pair of items actually involves generating a random number for each item and comparing those. New random numbers will be generated for every comparison, so comparing the same two items twice could indicate that they need reordering on one occasion and not on the next.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - Yes, but that's precisely what you want to have happen here. It's trying to sort them randomly. But maybe I don't understand the downside of this?

Comment: No it is not what you want to happen.  I'm not talking about calling `OrderBy` multiple times.  I'm talking about calling it once.  Each time you call `OrderBy`, each item in the list will be compared to various others multiple times and you do NOT want a different random value to represent it on each of those occasions.

Comment: Hmmm... I just ran a test and it looks like I may have been lied to, although I did do some reading on the subject and it was fairly widely supported, so I would think that there must be some truth to it.  I'll have to investigate further I think.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - Why not? I'm trying to randomize the list. What's wrong with with different random numbers each time?

Comment: I think you're missing the point, although my testing indicates that the point might be moot. As I said though, there were a significant number of people who were supporting that point, so there may well be some truth to it but not quite what I thought. Regardless, I'm not saying that it is bad that a different random number gets assigned to each original value each time you want to randomise. Of course that's good. What I'm saying is that it is bad if you randomise once and, within that one run, different random numbers get assigned to the same original value at different times.

Comment: OK, I believe that I've worked out when there's an issue and when there's not. There's no problem when you call `OrderBy` and pass a `Func(Of T)` because the delegate is invoked once only for each item. There is a problem if you want to randomise in place though, e.g. `List.Sort` or `Array.Sort`. If you provide a `Comparison(Of T)` delegate in such cases and that generates the random numbers then you will get multiple random numbers generated for the same item. I must have been doing the latter when the issue was pointed out to me and I didn't realise the difference.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - I'm still not understanding what the problem is when "multiple random numbers generated for the same item". That's what I want to understand.

Comment: You understand that sorting a list involves multiple comparisons of pairs of items, right? It's quite possible that the same pair of items could be compared multiple times. If you're comparing random numbers for items and you compare the same pair of items twice, you'd want to use the same random numbers for each comparison, right? If you don't then it is quite likely that the first comparison would order them one and then the second comparison would order them the other way. If that kept up then you could end up swapping the two items indefinitely.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - Ah, it's the "swapping the two items indefinitely" that I was missing. I see your point. Thank you for being patient.

Comment: So my conclusion is that, if you're using `OrderBy` or the like then sorting by `Random` values is OK because there will only be a single key generated per item. Check [this](https://pastebin.com/1MTqkBdy) out for a demonstration of that. If you want to randomise in place though, you'll need to provide a method that takes two items and performs a comparison and, in that case, multiple keys will be generated for the same item and that can be problematic. Check [this](https://pastebin.com/6NWtbaqT) out for a demonstration of that.

Answer (score 0):

The first loop creates a copy of your deck of cards.

The second loop picks a random card from the available cards in the temporary deck and iterates through your original deck and places that randomly picked card. In that loop, the picked card is removed from the temporary deck.

The random number of the card to be picked is in the range of the number of cards left in the temporary deck, so you'll never get any duplicate picks and you'll only have to do 52 iterations.

```
Sub ShuffleDeck()
    'creates a new deck to copy to, a list of random numbers, and a randomizer object to make random number in a range
    Dim tempDeck As New List(Of Card)
    Dim randNum As New Random
    For i As Integer = 0 To 51
        tempDeck.Add(deckList(i))
    Next

    For i As Integer = 0 To 51
        Dim randCardNum As Integer = randNum.Next(0, tempDeck.Count)
        deckList(i) = tempDeck(randCardNum)
        tempDeck.Remove(tempDeck(randCardNum))
    Next
End Sub
```